# Is there a name for graphs admitting this type of colouring?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology, puzzle, coloring

I was trying to solve this [prisoner puzzle](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/jan/23/can-you-solve-it-prisoners-and-boxes) in the Guardian.

We can create a graph where the nodes are the 16 possible combinations of four coins, and there is an edge between A and B iff starting from position A, you can flip a single coin to obtain position B. In fact, this graph turns out to be the [hypercube graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph) $Q_4$.

Then, to solve the puzzle, we have to find a 4-colouring of $Q_4$ such that for every node A and every colour $c$, there is a node B of colour $c$ adjacent to A. In other words, each node has a neighbour of any given colour. There are many such colourings - for example, treating the positions as 4-bit binary numbers, we can do $\min(x,15-x) \bmod 4$.

My question is: **is there a name for such a colouring, or for a graph admitting such a colouring? Has this notion been studied at all in the literature?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a closely related and more well-studied concept: [domatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domatic_number).

A [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) in a graph $G$ is a subset $U \subset V(G)$ such that every vertex of $G$ is either contained in $U$, or has a neighbor in $U$.

We can extend this to coloring graphs by analogy. An ordinary (proper) coloring of a graph is a partition of the vertices into *independent* sets: the set of all vertices of a color must be a independent set (where no vertices are adjacent), and the color classes are a partition of the vertices. A **domatic partition** of a graph is a partition of the vertices into dominating sets.

From here, the **domatic number** is the maximum number of dominating sets in a domatic partition. It is the *maximum* number rather than the *minimum* number, unlike the ordinary notion of graph coloring, because finding a domatic partition gets harder as you increase the number of colors.

A domatic partition of the hypercube would solve an easier version of the puzzle in the Guardian: one in which we have to flip *up to one* coin, but leaving all coins as they are is a valid move.

---

What we want for the Guardian puzzle is a stronger notion of dominating sets: a set $U$ such that every vertex of $G$, whether or not it's contained in $U$, has a neighbor in $U$. Such a variant *has* been considered in research: it is called a [total dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Variants) or a strongly-dominating set.

So if we want a version of domatic number that requires the sets in the partition to be total dominating sets, we might call it a **total domatic number**.

This is a somewhat more obscure notion (by which I mean that it doesn't have a Wikipedia page) but it has been studied (under the name you'd expect, no less). It appears to have been first introduced in the paper [Total domination in graphs](https://doi.org/10.1002/net.3230100304) by Cockayne, Dawes, and Hedetniemi.